# Sort list of list with dates strings python

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort my list of list with `a.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` or `a.sort()`. The first element of my date is the day and I need to sort by it.

```
a = [['1/8/2018', 71], ['10/8/2018', 76], ['11/8/2018', 6], ['12/8/2018', 60], ['13/8/2018', 81], ['14/8/2018', 74], ['15/8/2018', 7], ['16/8/2018', 77], ['17/8/2018', 81], ['18/8/2018', 69], ['19/8/2018', 66], ['2/8/2018', 81], ['20/8/2018', 74], ['21/8/2018', 88], ['22/8/2018', 92], ['23/8/2018', 90], ['24/8/2018', 84], ['25/8/2018', 66], ['26/8/2018', 64], ['27/8/2018', 82], ['28/8/2018', 82], ['29/8/2018', 79], ['3/8/2018', 8], ['4/8/2018', 64], ['5/8/2018', 64], ['6/8/2018', 12], ['7/8/2018', 8], ['8/8/2018', 83], ['9/8/2018', 77]]
```

the results I need:

```
[['1/8/2018', 71],['2/8/2018', 81], ['3/8/2018', 8], ['4/8/2018', 64], ['5/8/2018', 64], ['6/8/2018', 12],['7/8/2018', 8], ['8/8/2018', 83], ['9/8/2018', 77], ['10/8/2018', 76], ['11/8/2018', 6], ['12/8/2018', 60], ['13/8/2018', 81], ['14/8/2018', 74], ['15/8/2018', 7], ['16/8/2018', 77], ['17/8/2018', 81], ['18/8/2018', 69], ['19/8/2018', 66], ['20/8/2018', 74], ['21/8/2018', 88], ['22/8/2018', 92], ['23/8/2018', 90], ['24/8/2018', 84], ['25/8/2018', 66], ['26/8/2018', 64], ['27/8/2018', 82], ['28/8/2018', 82], ['29/8/2018', 79]]
```

Comment: Looks like your current code is comparing those dates as a `string` instead of `numbers` or `dates`. Try to convert that into `date` than do your stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split`:

```
a = [['1/8/2018', 71], ['10/8/2018', 76], ['11/8/2018', 6], ['12/8/2018', 60], ['13/8/2018', 81], ['14/8/2018', 74], ['15/8/2018', 7], ['16/8/2018', 77], ['17/8/2018', 81], ['18/8/2018', 69], ['19/8/2018', 66], ['2/8/2018', 81], ['20/8/2018', 74], ['21/8/2018', 88], ['22/8/2018', 92], ['23/8/2018', 90], ['24/8/2018', 84], ['25/8/2018', 66], ['26/8/2018', 64], ['27/8/2018', 82], ['28/8/2018', 82], ['29/8/2018', 79], ['3/8/2018', 8], ['4/8/2018', 64], ['5/8/2018', 64], ['6/8/2018', 12], ['7/8/2018', 8], ['8/8/2018', 83], ['9/8/2018', 77]]
new_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:[int(i) for i in x[0].split('/')])
```

Output:

```
[['1/8/2018', 71], ['2/8/2018', 81], ['3/8/2018', 8], ['4/8/2018', 64], ['5/8/2018', 64], ['6/8/2018', 12], ['7/8/2018', 8], ['8/8/2018', 83], ['9/8/2018', 77], ['10/8/2018', 76], ['11/8/2018', 6], ['12/8/2018', 60], ['13/8/2018', 81], ['14/8/2018', 74], ['15/8/2018', 7], ['16/8/2018', 77], ['17/8/2018', 81], ['18/8/2018', 69], ['19/8/2018', 66], ['20/8/2018', 74], ['21/8/2018', 88], ['22/8/2018', 92], ['23/8/2018', 90], ['24/8/2018', 84], ['25/8/2018', 66], ['26/8/2018', 64], ['27/8/2018', 82], ['28/8/2018', 82], ['29/8/2018', 79]]
```

Comment: Or actually convert the strings to dates to make the code less cryptic.

Comment: This will sort by day then by month then by year.

Answer (score 3):

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
a = [['1/8/2018', 71], ['10/8/2018', 76], ['11/8/2018', 6], ['12/8/2018', 60], ['13/8/2018', 81], ['14/8/2018', 74], ['15/8/2018', 7], ['16/8/2018', 77], ['17/8/2018', 81], ['18/8/2018', 69], ['19/8/2018', 66], ['2/8/2018', 81], ['20/8/2018', 74], ['21/8/2018', 88], ['22/8/2018', 92], ['23/8/2018', 90], ['24/8/2018', 84], ['25/8/2018', 66], ['26/8/2018', 64], ['27/8/2018', 82], ['28/8/2018', 82], ['29/8/2018', 79], ['3/8/2018', 8], ['4/8/2018', 64], ['5/8/2018', 64], ['6/8/2018', 12], ['7/8/2018', 8], ['8/8/2018', 83], ['9/8/2018', 77]]
a.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d/%m/%Y"))
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[['1/8/2018', 71], ['2/8/2018', 81], ['3/8/2018', 8], ['4/8/2018', 64], ['5/8/2018', 64], ['6/8/2018', 12], ['7/8/2018', 8], ['8/8/2018', 83], ['9/8/2018', 77], ['10/8/2018', 76], ['11/8/2018', 6], ['12/8/2018', 60], ['13/8/2018', 81], ['14/8/2018', 74], ['15/8/2018', 7], ['16/8/2018', 77], ['17/8/2018', 81], ['18/8/2018', 69], ['19/8/2018', 66], ['20/8/2018', 74], ['21/8/2018', 88], ['22/8/2018', 92], ['23/8/2018', 90], ['24/8/2018', 84], ['25/8/2018', 66], ['26/8/2018', 64], ['27/8/2018', 82], ['28/8/2018', 82], ['29/8/2018', 79]]
```

Comment: See for more reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-sort-a-Python-date-string-list